# React Create-react-app issue, stuck at Installing on my one pc and running smoothly on another

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, npm-install, npx

I have tried every thing, installed 4-5 node.js files, older versions newer versions but nothing worked.

My create react app command stuck on one point.

I have latest node.js

I run this npx create-react-app new

Then it stuck at Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

And

I have done same thing on my other PC it work fine their.

Both Machines are have Window as OP.

Need Help

Comment: You'll have to show what error you're getting for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: I am geting nothing installation stuck here 

Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...